# How to handle the inner query in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Created an Rest Post-type API in nodeJS,in which :
I am executing two queries here.
1. Firstly Executing the query on answers table to fetch user-Id and answer detail as well in that table. // i have check in the my console they show me two user-Id
2.Second ,executing the query on users table to fetch users detail on the basis of user-Id that i pass in find function. // check my console they show me two answer object because i have two user-Id.
------------------ above process work fine ---------------------
Now, i got stuck because , i have two merge both result into one object.
I'm doing this but isn't work perfect.Help me out here..!!

My code : -

```
app.post('/getTopAns', function(req, res) {
 console.log("inside getTopAns ");
 var questionId=req.body.questionId;
 mongoose.model('answers').find({
   questionId:questionId,
   compliance:"Y"
 }, function(err, ansResult){
   for (var i = 0;i<ansResult.length;i++) {
   mongoose.model('users').findOne({
       userId:ansResult[i].userId,
   }, function(err,usrResult){
       var obj = {
           followerLength : usrResult.follower.length,
           upvote : ansResult[i].upvote
       }
    })
    console.log(obj);  
   }
});
})
```

Comment: What is the expected output? How does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should first log ansResult to see if db is returning this. If it is, then check usrResult. If both are returned, I usually use lodash's assign or merge to merge two objects into one

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using promises instead of callback to handle async easier with node.js. The flow is to get the first call result, map the array of result into a list of promises which we can wait for the result by using `Promise.all`. Finally map the second results which the first list.

```
app.post("/getTopAns", function(req, res) {
  console.log("inside getTopAns ");
  var questionId = req.body.questionId;
  mongoose.model("answers")
  .find({
    questionId: questionId,
    compliance: "Y"
  })
  .then(ansResult => {
    const promises = ansResult.map(ans => {
      return mongoose.model("users")
        .findOne({ userId: ansResult[i].userId })
    })

    return Promise.all(promises)
      .then(usrResults => {
        return usrResults.map((usrResult, i) => {
          followerLength: usrResult.follower.length,
          upvote: ansResult[i].upvote
        })
      })
  })
  .then(results => {
    console.log('got all results here', results)
  }) 
});
```

It can be even better using `async/await`.

```
app.post("/getTopAns", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("inside getTopAns ");
  var questionId = req.body.questionId;
  const ansResult = mongoose.model("answers")
    .find({
      questionId: questionId,
      compliance: "Y"
    })

  const promises = ansResult.map(ans => {
    return mongoose.model("users")
      .findOne({ userId: ansResult[i].userId })
  })

  const usrResults = await Promise.all(promises)

  const results =  usrResults.map((usrResult, i) => {
    followerLength: usrResult.follower.length,
    upvote: ansResult[i].upvote
  })

  console.log('got all results here', results)
});
```

More information can be found here: https://medium.com/@ThatGuyTinus/callbacks-vs-promises-vs-async-await-f65ed7c2b9b4